# Where can I get programId after deploying the program through solana playground on devnet?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang

Here is the account where is the program id that i can use in anchor https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2u1dmgThKZyMUBTAGJCEr5oQivGrufKWhFfQXKpwV1kgv35ymYeTPiTWC8Nx842BJegANKpknVyCZdacmgn17y6q?cluster=devnet

Comment: If your question is answered, please mark it as accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a gif for how to locate the `programId` on Solana Playground!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To add to the previous answers, `declare_id!` on your code will automatically update to match your program id when you build the project.

Answer (score 2):

The program id is `8Xnz4ta9XGsq7A7mHTeMd9eg4JQoT7z1TxoiKdp3StVY`

You can also find the program id on the build tab in solana playground:

[image: screenshot from solana playground]